# How to center these links?

Tags: html, hyperlink, center

I don't know anything about HTML codes and I'm using a template I used online for my blog, www.lemontierres.com. I have some links to pages at the top of my blog but I want to have them in the center instead of on the left side of my blog, and I don't know how to fix this? I Googled and found some answers but I don't know how to apply them to my situation. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<div class='nav'>
<ul class='menu' id='menu'>
    <li><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.lemontierres.com/p/about-me.html">about me</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.lemontierres.com/p/business-inquiries.html">contact/business inquiries</a></li>

    <li><a class='drop-ctg' href='#'/>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'> 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'> 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'> 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'> 4</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple CSS would solve this

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. The first CSS puts all of the `<li>` elements inline rather than stacked and the second centers all of the text.

```
ul.menu li {
    display: inline;
}
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrejkr2z/)

Answer (score 0):

put `<center>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </center>` 
That is how I would do it.
Basically you just need to put the center tags around the code for the links.
If that doesnt work do what JRULLE and Vector said.